# merging .root files one by one using hadd

Tags: bash, shell, merge, root

I have 2800 root files to in a directory. I want to merge them one by one, If I use

`SOURCE_DIRECTORY="/input_directory/" OUTPUT_FILE="/output_directory/output.root" hadd -f "$OUTPUT_FILE" "$SOURCE_DIRECTORY"/*.root`

It will load all the root files at the begining and merge them all, which requires big memory. If one could load and merge file one by one it would not require big memory. Any suggestion will be appriciated.
I am using root 6.24.06

Comment: Have you looked at the `hadd` manpage? There seems to be a `-n` option (_"open at most 'maxopenedfiles' at once"_). Couldn't that help you minimize the memory load?